# How do I create a reactive dataframe from merging two dataframes

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app
I have two dataframes which create a third dataframe. I want various things to be performed by a user on this merged dataframe. As a result this third dataframe should be reactive. The dataframe is only populated once the 'Merge' button has been pressed

What I dont understand is how to create a reactive dataframe when it does not exist when the app starts up.

My code so far:

## ui.R

```
fluidPage(tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
 tabPanel("Merged Dataset", tableOutput("table2"),
           actionButton("Endomerge2",label = "Endomerge2"),
           DT::dataTableOutput("pathTable"),
           DT::dataTableOutput("endoTable"),
           DT::dataTableOutput("mergedTable")
  )
))
```

## server.R

```
library(shiny)

RV <- reactiveValues(data = DataToMerge1)
RV2 <- reactiveValues(data = DataToMerge2)
RV3<-reactiveVal(0)



server <- function(input, output) {      
  output$endotable = DT::renderDT({
    RV$data
  })
  output$pathTable = DT::renderDT({
    RV2$data
  })
  output$mergedTable = DT::renderDT({
    RV3$data
  })



 #Button to merge the dataframes on

    observeEvent(input$Endomerge2,{
    RV3$data<-Endomerge2(RV$data,"AcolumnToMerge",RV2$data,"AcolumnToMerge")
  },ignoreInit = TRUE)

}
```

At the moment I get the error of type of closure is not subsettable but I suspect that is just hiding a bigger error. 
So how can I create a new dataframe and show it in a new datatable in Shiny?

Comment: You are using `Endomerge2` as a function.  Have you tried `RV3$data <- merge(RV$data, RV2$data, by = "AcolumnToMerge")`

Comment: @akrun I have to use Endomerge2 for various reasons but it does return a dataframe so this shouldnt be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reactiveVal()` creates a single reactive value, not a list, so you cannot add a list item named `data`. Try this:

```r
RV <- reactiveValues(data = DataToMerge1)
RV2 <- reactiveValues(data = DataToMerge2)
RV3 <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame())



server <- function(input, output) {      
  output$endotable = DT::renderDT({
    RV$data
  })
  output$pathTable = DT::renderDT({
    RV2$data
  })
  output$mergedTable = DT::renderDT({
    RV3$data
  })



 #Button to merge the dataframes on

    observeEvent(input$Endomerge2,{
    RV3$data<-Endomerge2(RV$data,"AcolumnToMerge",RV2$data,"AcolumnToMerge")
  },ignoreInit = TRUE)

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Wil. I didnt realise it was as simple as just adding an empty data frame as a reactive value

Comment: It's more about the difference between `reactiveVal()` and `reactiveValues()` and how you create the object(s) and assign value(s) to them. IMHO they can be quite nuanced and it is not always intuitive whether one is better than the other in a given situation.